# MissingSourceFile while requiring 'active_support/inflector/inflections'

Tags: ruby, bundler, activesupport

I recently updated my application to use Bundler, but I'm having some troubles. I'm using a gem that depends on `activesupport 2.3+` and I can't get it to work with Bundler. Passenger crashes while trying to load my application. A `MissingSourceFile` error occurs while it tries to load `activesupport`. Does anybody know how to solve this issue or what I might do wrong? It doesn't happen with `activesupport 3.0+`, but the gem I'm using relies on `2.x`.

```
no such file to load -- active_support/inflector/inflections (MissingSourceFile)

0   /opt/ruby/1.8.7-ee-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb   182 in `require'
1   /opt/ruby/1.8.7-ee-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb   182 in `require'
2   /opt/ruby/1.8.7-ee-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb   547 in `new_constants_in'
3   /opt/ruby/1.8.7-ee-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb   182 in `require'
4   /opt/ruby/1.8.7-ee-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/roxml-3.1.6/lib/roxml.rb  4   
.
.
.
9   config.ru   8   in `require'
```

Answer (score 0):

Requiring inflections like that is the ActiveSupport 3 style. As you can see,

```
activesupport-2.3.9 $ find . -name "inflections.rb"
./lib/active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections.rb
./lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb
./lib/active_support/inflections.rb
```

If possible, the offending gem should do something like:

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/version'
if ActiveSupport::VERSION::MAJOR == 3
  require 'active_support/inflector/inflections'
end
```

That's what [the remote_table gem](https://github.com/seamusabshere/remote_table/blob/master/lib/remote_table.rb) does.

Comment: What I meant to show with the file listing is that active_support/inflector/inflections doesn't even exist in ActiveSupport 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using roxml gem, switch to 3.1.3 version.

Answer (score 0):

I was running with sudo and it works fine!

Check the permissions of the folders enviroment:

```
ENV['X_DEBIAN_SITEID'] ||= 'default'
ENV['RAILS_ETC'] ||= "/etc/redmine/#{ENV['X_DEBIAN_SITEID']}"
ENV['RAILS_LOG'] ||= "/var/log/redmine/#{ENV['X_DEBIAN_SITEID']}"
ENV['RAILS_VAR'] ||= "/var/lib/redmine/#{ENV['X_DEBIAN_SITEID']}"
ENV['RAILS_CACHE'] ||= "/var/cache/redmine/#{ENV['X_DEBIAN_SITEID']}"
ENV['SCHEMA'] ||= "#{ENV['RAILS_CACHE']}/schema.db"
```